# Strange page bug on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, google-chrome

I'm using [Choosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) and [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) in my project. Here is jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/7HLyZ/3/

Try to open this jsFiddle on 2 browsers: Firefox and Chrome

On chrome it works just fine.

On firefox open link above. Press on first colapsible opener. It will hide (close) inner part then press it one more time to open: you will see that it shows only choosen, 
not inner div. Here is what I see after 3 times pressing (Firefox)

[image]

And here is how it should be  (Chrome)

[image]

What am I missing? how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: http://jsfiddle.net/7HLyZ/35/

Changes:

`.collapse.in {height: auto;}`

`<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">Collapsible Group Item #1</a>`

`<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo" aria-hidden="true">Collapsible Group Item #2</a>`