# Strange css overflow issue

Tags: html, css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strange page bug on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664926/strange-page-bug-on-firefox)

I'm using [Choosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) and [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) in my project. [Here is jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/7HLyZ/3/)
Try to open this on Firefox (On chrome it works just fine) Press on first accordion item opener. It will close inner part. Then press it one more time to open: you will see that it shows only textbox, not inner div.

Here is screenshots of what I see after 3 times pressing on Firefox

[image]

And here is how it should be (on Chrome)

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

interesting behavior in Firefox! but if you take the below line out it works fine.

```
 .collapse.in { overflow: visible; }
```

If you don't set any overflow by default it is set to visible by the browser any way so no need to explicitly set it.  refer to here http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/

Comment: Take it and see what happens. I don't see dropdown at all.

Comment: Take it out and everything works perfect on this end.

Comment: What version of firefox are you usin? if I take it out the latest version of firefox is working fine.